# Logic question regarding a logical truth

Tags: logic, proof, deduction, symbolic-logic

Is the following logically true? ∃x[Cube(x) →∀yCube(y)]

I think that it is logically true. When translated into truth functional form we have: A→B. A truth table shows that it is not a tautology but since one entry in the column is T, it is TT-possible. Thus, logically true.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

It is an instance of a "logical truth", and specifically an example of [universally valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity#Valid_formula) formula of predicate logic, but not a (propositional) [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples).

If all objects are **Cube**, the formula is True.

The tricky case is when not all objects are **Cube**: in this case **∀yCube(y)** is False.

But if **∀yCube(y)** is False, we have some objects **a** such that **Cube(a)** is False.

Thus, **Cube(a) →∀yCube(y)** is False → False, i.e. True.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two different systems of logic.  Sentential or propositional logic uses variables to represent whole sentences (hence the name), and connects them with operators such as if-then.  Truth tables are used in sentential logic.  (First-order) predicate logic extends sentential logic by adding object-predicate constructions (like "x is a cube") and quantifiers ("there is an x such that").

Truth tables can't be used in predicate logic.  To see why, consider the sentence `(x) x=x` (for all x, x is identical with x).  This sentence is logically true.  But if you tried to represent it in sentential logic, you would get simply `p`.  And `p` is not logically true — one row of its truth table is false.

(Also, logical truth, logical necessity, and tautology are all synonymous.  So in sentential logic, finding a row of the truth table where the sentence is false shows that it's *not* logically true.)

In more-or-less natural English, your sentence is equivalent to the following:  "either something is not a cube or everything is a cube."  It will probably be easy to see that this is logically true.  (Maura ALLEGRANZA's answer gives more detail here.)  But that's not yet a formal proof.

Here's a formal proof using reductio ad absurdum:

```
WTS: (Ex)[Cx -> (y) Cy]

1. Assume for RAA: -(Ex)[Cx -> (y) Cy]
2. (x) -[Cx -> (y) Cy]
3. -[Ca -> (y) Cy]
4. Ca & -(y) Cy
5. Ca
6. -(y) Cy
7. (Ey) -Cy
8. -Cb
9. -[Cb -> (y) Cy]  (from 2)
10. Cb & -(y) Cy
11. Cb 
-><- (8, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the Fitch software (Sorry, it uses P instead of Cube):

[image]